# Divide sentence into two lines on RPi LCD 16x2 screen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

If the input of the question is unknown and can be of almost any length, how do I divide it into two parts and then display those two parts as two separate lines on the Raspberry Pi 16x2 LCD screen?

Comment: I haven't used the 16x2 LCD module with RPi.But I suppose you can make a method where it counts for 16 characters and moves to a new line.

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  You don't appear to have *any* code yet, which suggests that you need tutorial help, not Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screen is 16 characters in width and 2 characters in height.

```
max_char_len = 16
string = "String with more than 16 characters in length"

if len(string)-1 > max_char_len: 
    string = string[:max_char_len].strip() + '\n' + string[max_char_len:].strip()
```

Ouput of `print(string)`;

```
String with more
than 16 characters in length
```

For more lines, use this recursive;

```
def insert_return(string, at):
    for i in range(len(string)-1):
        if i != 0 and i % at == 0 and string[i+1]:
            return string[:i+1].strip() + '\n' + insert_return(string[i+1:].strip(), at)
    return string

print(insert_return(string, max_char_len))
```

Output;

```
String with more
than 16 characte
rs in length
```